# Showing that $\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb N}\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is not a direct summand of $\prod_{i\in\mathbb N}\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$

Tags: modules

I know that if the direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $I$ were a direct summand of the direct product of countably many copies, $R$ (direct summand as $R$-modules), then the complement would be a direct summand isomorphic to $R/I$. But I can't think of any properties of the quotient that would preclude it from being a subgroup. Could I have a hint?

Comment: Pretty sure it is a direct summand... ? Both groups are just vector spaces over $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: Is the infinite sum you refer to the obvious embedding into the infinite product, or are you after something more general, where there is _some_ subgroup of the infinite product that is isomorphic to the infinite sum?

Comment: It's the obvious embedding.

Comment: And how are we supposed to give a proof for something which is wrong? :-) Please address Dustan's comment.

Comment: @Martin OP hides a critical fact within the text: "direct summand as $R$-modules," where the sentence structure indicates what $R$ is. Surely this could be stated more clearly and up-front, though...

Comment: If the question is "not a direct summand as an $\prod \mathbb{F}_2$-module," you can completely classify all such direct summands by classifying the idempotents in $\prod \mathbb{F}_2$, then looking at their images. (Hint: every element is idempotent.)

Comment: ^Why does that work? I know that all finitely generated ideals of $R$ are principal and thus generated by an idempotent, but this $I$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: That is the laziest way of addressing a comment I have ever seen.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you also didn't bother to post a comment explaining that your edit was meant to address my comment, leaving others to do that hard work for you.

Comment: Oh, I see. blue said that we should clean up the comments after I edit the OP, but I guess I shouldn't have deleted my comment anyway.

Comment: Ah, I see. My bad then, I just missed a conversation apparently. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R=\prod k$ (infinitely many copies) be considered a module over itself, $k$ a field. Then $\bigoplus k$ is a submodule of $R$. Suppose that $N$ is any other nontrivial submodule (equivalently, ideal) of $R$.

Show that $N$ and $\bigoplus k$ intersect nontrivially: take an arbitrary nonzero element of the former, and multiply it by an appropriately coordinate-annihilating element of $R$, and you remain in $N$...

Comment: Thanks! And I think you mean that any ideal intersects the direct sum nontrivially, right?

Comment: Erm, yes. ${}{}$

Comment: @Nishant In other words, $\oplus k$ is an essential submodule of $\prod k$. The only essential direct summand of the regular module is the entire module.